# return type of class function not defined

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

So i have a class "Sentence" that #includes "Word".

Sentence is a linked list of words.

My assignment states that I have to overload "operator+" so that

```
Sentence s = "dog jumped.";
Word w = "The";

W+s; //should return a new sentence that says "The dog jumped high."
```

Keep in mind that I have to overload operator+. That's what I'm being graded on

However, since, Sentence includes Word, its not defined yet. I'll get an error

```
return type 'class Sentence' is incomplete
```

and
    invalid use of incomplete type 'const class Sentence'

here's my code for the overload

```
class Sentence; //forward declaration
Sentence Word::operator+(const Sentence &sentence) const{
  Sentence *s = new Sentence(sentence.getCopy()); //make a new sentence that's a copy of the     parameter
  Word *w = new Word;

  Sentence::node *l = new Sentence::node; //make new linked list node
  (*(l->w)) = (*w); //Set word of node
  l->next = (*s).getFirs(); // set new node to point to first node of the sentence object
  (*s).setFirs(l); // point first pointer to the new node

  return *s;
}
```

I also tried a separate way of overloading the operator outside of the class that looked liked this

```
Sentence operator+(const Word &word, const Sentence &sentence);
```

Which caused errors saying it's defined multiple times

Comment: you try to return type that is only forward declared. Imagine you are compiler, user says that there will be class Sentance somewhere in the future, so you know only that one thing, and then he tries to return instance of it. You cant really know what the size is, so how much space to allocate for the temporary and such. You will have to split this code so that the operator+ is at such place that can see definitions of both Sentence and Word

Comment: Defining this operator outside of the class is the way to go in this case, possibly aided by friend declarations or utility functions. Why it didn't work? I don't know, you must have made a mistake, but it's impossible to say without looking at the code (reduced to a minimal example, of course).

Comment: You seem to have been posting about this same code for days now and still have not fixed the basic issue of where you put the class definitions for `Word` and `Sentence`.  Fix that first and then all the other problems will go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is that when you forward-declare `Sentence` you don't provide the compiler with the information that it needs to produce the code that calls methods of the forward-declared class or return it by value. All you can do with a forward-declared class is making a pointer to it. For everything else, a full definition must be available.

In the implementation file of the `Word` class include the header file with the definition of the `Sentence` class. This will fix this compile issue.

As far as the implementation goes, this line looks inefficient:

```
Sentence *s = new Sentence(sentence.getCopy());
```

you are making another copy of the sentence that is already a copy by passing it to the copy constructor. These two alternatives should work as well without unnecessary copying:

```
Sentence *s = &sentence.getCopy();
```

or

```
Sentence *s = new Sentence(sentence);
```

Of course that would not eliminate a memory leak resulting from returning a copy of a dynamically allocated object without calling `delete`.

This will avoid the memory leak problem:

```
Sentence s(sentence);
```

Comment: `Sentence s(sentence);` looks a whole lot better than all of those options, and avoids leaking memory.